# Type safe handling of functional component props injected by an HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, high-order-component

**TL;DNR:** I'm using TypeScript 3.3.3. Is there a better way to declare props I need that are injected from an HOC, without making them visible to code consuming my component?

---

Consider a basic component that is decorated with the `withNamespaces` HOC. The library and HOC used is arbitrary, I've run into this problem with any components that follow this pattern. It's also a bit of a problem with class components, but I'll focus on functions here.

```
// MyComponent.tsx
import * as React from 'react'
import { withNamespaces, WithNamespaces } from 'react-i18next'


const MyComponent: React.FunctionalComponent = ({ children, t }) => (
  <a title={t('my translated text')}>{children}</a>
)

export default withNamespaces('my-component')(MyComponent)
```

I've got a second file that contains tests for my component.

```
// MyComponent.spec.tsx
import * as React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

it('should render', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent>Test</MyComponent>)

   expect(wrapper.toExist()).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Now this won't compile because `t` is not defined in my props. I can try fixing this a number of ways. In this example, the third-party library gives us a `WithNamespaces` type that defines `t`, and a bunch of other things that `withNamespaces` injects into our component, which we can use as or merge with our props type definition.

```
 const MyComponent: React.FunctionalComponent<WithNamespaces> = ({children, t}) => ( // ...
```

Now `MyComponent` compiles and gives me nice type safety as to my possible props. However, now my test file is angry because I haven't provided values for props the component definition expects, for example `t`. However, we know this is going to get injected by the HOC, so creating a mock or providing this prop with a value of some garbage is just confusing and unnecessary extra work to fix type problems.

```
// type is missing the following properties from WithNamespaces: t, etc., etc.
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent>Test</MyComponent>)
```

I can fudge that by making my component's props partial ala `FunctionalComponent<Partial<WithNamespaces>>`, but now I've got to conditionally check those props I need or use `t!` (not-null assertion operator), and these seem unnecessarily annoying, melts the brains of people new to TS, and seems a little smelly.

I can also just cast the props inside my render function (or in classes, any method that is accessing props) to hide the injected props from my consumers:

```
const MyComponent: React.FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  const { children, t } = props as WithNamespaces
  return (
    <a title={t('my translated text')}>{children}</a>
  )
}
```

This is a little handwavy and inelegant, though. There are a multitude of other ways, like casting to any and back to something that doesn't reference WithNamespaces, etc., but surely there's a better way to do this?

**Misc**

`withNamespace` does have a definition that uses the [`Omit` pattern](https://dev.to/busypeoples/notes-on-typescript-pick-exclude-and-higher-order-components-40cp) to exclude the props in `WithNamespaces` from the returned type, but that doesn't seem to be working, at least with functional components.

Comment: What versions are you using? I just installed the definitions of `react-i18next` (`"@types/react": "^16.8.8",
    "i18next": "^15.0.7",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-i18next": "^10.5.2"`) and it works as expected (`t` is not required)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm stuck on the latest react-i18next@9 because I'm using next-i18next to integrate with NextJS  and they don't support 10 yet. However, I've run into the same problem using other HOCs, for example Material-UI's `withStyles`.